# Подскажите как менять контент на сайте в зависимости от гео запроса?

Tags: javascript

Нужно чтобы когда на сайн входит клиент с СНГ, был один контент цены в грн, а если на сайт входят с европы и сша контент немного отличался и цены были другие и в евро. Как можно это реализовать?

Сайт будет писаться на html/css, JavaScript.

Comment: Посмотри библиотеки для интернационализации. Тебе ведь и язык документа нужен разный. Ну а дальше просто: в зависимости от геолокации у тебя будут разные функции получения текста конкретного элемента. Вариант @Valeria "хорош" только для очень стабильного сайта, где почти никогда ничего не меняется. Если же меняется, то при таком подходе будет дублирование кода и вытекающие проблемы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Определяешь страну через ip или другие способы(смотри ссылку)
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489460/how-to-get-visitors-location-i-e-country-using-geolocation
2. Грузишь разные версии сайта/ разные страницы вроде: 
   my-site.com/ru 
   my-site.com/ua 
   my-site.com/us

Реализация на твой вкус и умения.